# python scripts issue (no module named ...) when starting in rc.local

Tags: python, dependency-management

I'm facing of a strange issue, and after a couple of hour of research I'm looking for help / explanation about the issue.
It's quite simple, I wrote a cgi server in python and I'm working with some libs including pynetlinux for instance.
When I'm starting the script from terminal with any user, it works fine, no bug, no dependency issue. But when I'm trying to start it using a script in rc.local, the following code produce an error.

`import sys, cgi, pynetlinux, logging`

it produce the following error :

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/var/simkiosk/cgi-bin/load_config.py", line 3, in 
      import cgi, sys, json, pynetlinux, loggin
   ImportError: No module named pynetlinux
```

Other dependencies produce similar issue.I suspect some few things like user who executing the script in rc.local (root normaly) and trying some stuff found on the web without success.

Somebody can help me ?

Thanx in advance.

Regards.

Ollie314

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to make sure if the module you want to import is installed properly. You can check if the name of the module exists in `pip list`

Then, in a python shell, check what the paths are where Python is looking for modules:

```
    import sys
    sys.path
```

In my case, the output is:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Finally, append those paths to $PATH variable in /etc/rc.local. Here is an example of my rc.local:

```
    #!/bin/sh -e
    #
    # rc.local
    #
    # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
    # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
    # value on error.
    #
    # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
    # bits.
    #
    # By default this script does nothing

    export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/python3.4:/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages"

    # Do stuff

    exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The path where your modules are install is probably normally sourced by .bashrc or something similar. .bashrc doesn't get sourced when it's not an interactive shell. /etc/profile is one place that you can put system wide path changes. Depending on what Linux version/distro it may use /etc/profile.d/ in which case /etc/profile runs all the scripts in /etc/profile.d, add a new shell script there with execute permissions and a .sh extention.